# Apostol equation for partial fraction simplification

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

In Apostol, the case that the partial fraction is presented as $\frac{C}{(u^2 + a^2)^m}$ can be done with the following reduction formula:

$$\int \frac{du}{(u^2 + a^2)^m} = \frac{1}{2a^2(m-1)} \frac{u}{(u^2 + a^2)^{m-1}} + \frac{2m - 3}{2a^2(m-1)} \int \frac{du}{(u^2 + a^2)^{m-1}}$$

The author states that this can be shown using integration by parts. I cannot figure how - i tried taking $dv = (u^2 + a^2)^{m-1}$ or $dv = 1 \Rightarrow v = u$. In case the $m = 2$, the integral can be done with trigonometric substitution. However, this general case is not as clear. Can someone show how this is obtained with integration by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you write
$$
\frac{1}{(u^2+a^2)^{m-1}}
=
u\cdot\frac{u}{(u^2+a^2)^m}+\frac{a^2}{(u^2+a^2)^m},
$$
and integrate by parts in the first term in the right-hand side, and then rearrange your terms.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Got it! @mickep, how did you come up with this transformation? Did you know it beforehand, solved similar examples, or you just see the pattern somehow? I think I myself would have never found how to integrate this, but with your transformation it is so simple!

Comment: @John Glad it helped. I've seen and done similar manipulations before.